# Syntax in cocoapods pod file. What does / mean?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

The following is example content of a Podfile

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'Project1/Models', '~> 0.3.4'
```

What does / mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The / precise that you use a subspec of pod spec. Please refer 
http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec